Typos in R can lead to major errors without warning - how to mitigate this?
There are situations in R where a typo can go undetected, resulting in incorrect results without any error or warning. The program runs as if there was no issue, but the output is erroneous.
Is there an option or method to force R to issue an error when such typos occur? The current behavior makes it challenging to trust the results of any program, as the program may appear correct but produce incorrect output.
Here are some examples illustrating this issue:
unique(mtcars$gear) # 4 3 5

idx = which(mtcars$gear <= 4)  # Correct indexing
idx = which(mtcars$gearx <= 4) # Typo: no error, incorrect result

x = mtcars$gear + mtcars$carb  # Correct calculation
x = mtcars$gearx + mtcars$carb # Typo: no error, incorrect result

stopifnot(mtcars$gear <= 4)  # Correct error handling
stopifnot(mtcars$gearx <= 4) # Typo: no error, incorrect error handling

library(assertthat)
assert_that(all(mtcars$gear <= 4))  # Correct error handling
assert_that(all(mtcars$gearx <= 4)) # Typo: no error, incorrect error handling

# Correct conditional statement
if (all(mtcars$gear <= 4)) {
  print("All gears are low")
}
# Typo: no error, incorrect conditional statement
if (all(mtcars$gearx <= 4)) {
  print("All gears are low")
}



Thank you @ada-lovelace for your response. The following is not a criticism of your response, which has some great tips. It's a criticism of the R language, since even with these tips, it still does not always catch typos.
Using with() removes the tight binding between the element and the object, which, while it fixes the particular issue that I mention above, introduces other issues.
with(mtcars, which(gearx <= 4))

correctly throws an error. But,
gearx = 1:5
with(mtcars, which(gearx <= 4))

does something that I did not intend.
The warnPartialMatchDollar option only catches some typos, but not others!
which(mtcars$gea <= 4) # Typo, warning
which(mtcars$gearx <= 4) # Typo, no warning

Based on your recommendation of avoiding $, I thought of using [ instead. This works with a data frame:
which(mtcars[,"gearx"] <= 4) # Typo, error

But it does not work with lists:
mylist = as.list(mtcars)
which(mylist[["gearx"]] <= 4) # Typo, no error

Finally. If avoiding $ is what's required to fix this issue, then I will do that. It just seems unfortunate, since $ is so easy, and other solutions (that I am seeing thus far) are more cumbersome.

And, To turn warnings into errors, set options(warn = 2) . , from Wickham, Advanced R. As a bad typist myself, you'll sense being hammered...

The dollar operator is 'known dangerous' in the sense you describe, it is best for interactive exploratory data work (where for example the tab completion works and help).
For programmatic work, you can index differently.  One option is using with() as in
> idx <- which(with(mtcars, gear <= 4))

If you try that with the (non-existing) gearx you can an error:
> idx <- which(with(mtcars, gearx <= 4))  
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :  
  object 'gearx' not found  
>  

Similarly, you can use certain idioms from either the tidyverse or data.table to index into data.frame object both more easily and more safely.  Just avoid the $ operator for subsetting.
You can also one or all of these options (see ?options):
 ‘warnPartialMatchArgs’: logical.  If true, warns if partial
      matching is used in argument matching.

 ‘warnPartialMatchAttr’: logical.  If true, warns if partial
      matching is used in extracting attributes via attr.

 ‘warnPartialMatchDollar’: logical.  If true, warns if partial
      matching is used for extraction by ‘$’.


Thank you for your thoughtful response. Please see my response to your response at the end of my original post.

Oh I am with you on the 'cumbersome' for some of the alternatives.  Some people like the (concise, expressive, performant) alternative data.table offers, others prefer dplyr with other tidyverse idioms to select and transform columns.  Your fight here really is with the $ operator, not with the R language (which, of course, is dynamically typed for a reason as this makes sense for data work).

I will start investigating this. Thank you! If you have specific examples (that work with both data frames / similar things as well as with lists), I would greatly appreciate them.

Your comment gave me an idea. See my response. What do you think? @ada-lovelace

Note the R docs also discourage using with() programmatically.

Programmatically, the [[ extractor as in mtcars[["gear"]] is preferred.

Or of course the same string with single brachkets. Directly, ie mtcara[, "gear"] or indirectly ie txt <- "gear"'; mtcars[, txt].  As a data.framereally is a list over vectors of equal lenth,mtcars[[txt]]andmtcars[["gear"]]` also work.  I am not sure I know one method as "preferred", I often need a row index too ...

As @ada-lovelace correctly points out, it's the $ operator that's the problem. Here's an idea. Let's redefine it! I am seriously considering loading the following code at the beginning of my programs.
`$` = function(obj, elem) {
  idx = which(names(obj) == substitute(elem))
  if (length(idx) != 1L) {
    stop(paste0("Element `", substitute(elem), "` not found in object `", substitute(obj), "`."))
  }
  obj[[idx]]
}

Let's test it:
identical(mtcars$gear, mtcars[,"gear"]) # Works with data.frames
mtcars$gearx # Typo: error!

mylist = as.list(mtcars)
identical(mylist$gear, mylist[["gear"]]) # Works with lists
mylist$gearx # Typo: error!

It appears to work as intended.

You can turn the warning on in options() and turn 'warnings as errors' on. Should amount to the same, possibly more robustly.

Could you please provide more detail? I don't know of a warning that could be turned on that would catch these errors. warnPartialMatchDollar catches mtcars$gea but not mtcars$gearx. (And mtcars$gea is not even as bad because it just matches to mtcars$gear.)

It cannot match gearx as there is not column named gearx.  If you want to subset with exact strings only, use a subsetting method that supports it.  txt <- "gear"; mtcars[, txt] works as does mtcars[[txt]].  These things are covered in many textbooks introducing R.
